# LazyInitializationException using hibernate enhancement with @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have this persistent entity with a lob field that gets eagerly fetched so I configured the **hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin** and made it lazy:

```java
@Lob
@Column(name = "MY_FIELD")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private byte[] lazyField;
```

Now I am getting **LazyInitializationException** at a fairly simple test:

```java
myJpaRepo.findAll().get(0).getLazyField()
```

> Unable to perform requested lazy initialization [MyEntity.lazyField] - no session and settings disallow loading outside the Session

I use Spring Boot and have not done anything specific to configure hibernate.
This test uses a h2 database.

MyRepo is annotated with @Transactional.

If I also annotate the executing method, there is no Exception thrown:

```java
@Transactional
public void test(){
    myJpaRepo.findAll().get(0).getLazyField()
}
```

Will I need to annotate as transactional every single time someone tries to fetch the lazy field, or is there something else I can do to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Error says that you are trying to access association outside of hibernate session/transaction boundary.

In this case you will have to annotate test method with @transaction as well so that you are well within transaction boundary and have active hibernate session.

Comment: Is that it? Should I annotate as @Transactional every time I get that field? I would imagine there would be some way to have the Hibernate Lazy Proxy do that.

Comment: Sadly not working in my case using Quarkus 1.10.2 although this might be a bug